# import table and stored procedures

Tags: sql, import, sql-server-2008-r2

I am trying to export the tables [around 40] and stored procedures [around 120+] in SQL Server 2008 R2 from dev server to prod server.

I have created a `.sql` file [right clicking on the database in SSMS, choosing `Tasks -> Generate Scripts`], but when I am trying to import the table and stored procedures into the prod server [right clicking on the database in SSMS, `New Query` then copying the content in] it is giving me a long list of errors

Mostly

> `There is already an object named 'tblMyTable' in the database`
>   `Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_MyTable'. Cannot insert
>   duplicate key in object 'dbo.tblMyTable'`

Any idea what I am doing wrong or what should be done? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you trying to put your development data in production as well?  Otherwise are you just looking to move DDL differences?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with your current technique is that assumes your target is an empty database.  So it will reinsert everything with no attempt at merging data and this is what causes your duplicate primary keys.  If you use Management Studio you have to do all the merging of data yourself.

My recommendation is first to look into redgate it's not free but all the time you will save it will be worth it. You will need to use both SQL Compare and Data Compare ( http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-data-compare/ ).

Another alternative is to use Visual Studio 2010 premium if you have it( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa833435.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd193261.aspx).  This gives both a data compare and a schema compare option.  It is not as good as redgate but I found it works most of the time.

If you are looking for free alternatives check out this stack post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/377388/are-there-any-free-alternatives-to-red-gates-tools-like-sql-compare.

Comment: You saved my whole day. Thanks mate.

Answer (score 0):

if you are importing the whole database to production you might as well do a restore with replace to the production database.

120 SPs and 20 tables seemed to be the whole database. so Restore with replace should be done.